# How can I pass multiple values to drupal_view()?

Tags: views, 8, theming

I'm on Drupal 8 and I have a view with multiple argument (list of node ID) but I can't embed this on my node.twig.html.

That's my code:

```
{% set myArray = [] %}
{% for item in content.field_articles_lies['#items'] %}
    {% set myArray = myArray|merge([item.entity.nid.value]) %}
{% endfor %}

{{ drupal_view('articles_lies','default', myArray()) }}
```

if I do that: `{{ drupal_view('articles_lies','default', myArray.0) }}`
it's ok but obviously only for one.

How can I pass an argument with multiple values to a view rendered via `drupal_view()` in a template?

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass an array. You have to implode the array to a string first. And use `'+'` as glue for OR and `','` as glue for AND. Like `'1+2+3'` or `'1,2,3'`. And maybe you also have to enable *Allow multiple values* in your view (in the very bottom of the contextual filter screen).

I have try that and it works but I'm not sure it's very clear:

```
{% set arguments = '' %}
{% set i = 0 %}
{% for item in content.field_articles_lies['#items'] %}
    {% if i == 0 %}
        {% set arguments = item.entity.nid.value %}
    {% else %}
        {% set arguments = arguments ~ "+" ~ item.entity.nid.value %}
    {% endif %}
    {% set i = i + 1 %}
{% endfor %}

{{ drupal_view('articles_lies', 'default', arguments) }}
```